# creating DocuSign event notification web hook in objective c

Tags: ios, docusignapi

I am trying to implement the web hook way to know the status of the DocuSign envelope but cannot find any objective-c code. Please help. Also i am lost reading [Using a webhook to track envelope status](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status). How do i create a web hook url so that docusign will call that url?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember  to upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please "check" the best answer that solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two questions:

- How do I include an eventNotification object as part of my Envelopes: create request when using the Objective-C SDK?
- How do I create a web hook URL that DocuSign will call?

I can help with the second question.

You need to create a *webhook listener*. It'll be a web application that can be called by the DocuSign Signature platform. You can write your webhook listener app in any language and it can run on any software stack.

As is true for any webhook, the unusual issue is that your listener app will be called by DocuSign. When it is called, your app can process the incoming information anyway that you want.

Your app's listener url must be available on the public internet so it can be reached by the DocuSign platform. For testing and development, you can use ngrok or similar services to provide a public internet address to your development server/machine.

**Developing for iOS?**

Remember that iPhones / iPads don't have an address on the public internet. So your webhook address can't be on those machines. But your webhook listener could be on some other server that the mobile app then polls.

Ask additional questions if you need more help.

**Added in response to a comment**

> So when the status changes, DocuSign will call my web hook and give an XML response and then my app will have to poll the web hook for the response. So I'll be polling the web hook and not DocuSign. Am I right?

Right: If your app is on a device/stack that doesn't allow incoming requests (eg mobile apps) then you can set up a server to act as a gateway: when the envelope or recipient status changes, DocuSign calls your webhook listener running on your gateway.

Then your app can poll your gateway as often as you like. You have some other alternatives too:

1. Your app could itself poll DocuSign once every 15 minutes (or less often).
2. Set up the gateway, but instead of your app polling the gateway, your app could use [Firebase messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) or an alternative push service designed for mobile apps. Your gateway would receive the incoming webhook messages from DocuSign and then distribute them using the push service.

> Also i tried setting up my web hook in php using deploy to Heroku link on git hub but how do i customise it to my needs? which is the web hook url that DocuSign called in this case?

You can customize the recipe examples by cloning (or just downloading) the recipe software. Then modify it as you wish. See the Heroku documentation if you then want to run your app on Heroku. Or you can run the software on your own machine and use ngrok to obtain a public url for it.

The recipe examples include an address that is given to DocuSign as part of the Envelopes: create call. I made the webhook address more visible in a new recipe framework. See this [github repo](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python). Use the *options* link in the navigation bar to see the details.

Comment: hanks for the reply. So when the status changes, DocuSign will call my web hook and give an XML response and then my app will have to poll the web hook for the response. So i'll be polling the web hook and not DocuSing. Am i right? Also i tried setting up my web hook in php using deploy to Heroku link on [git hub](https://github.com/DocuSign/recipe-010-webhook-php) but how do i customise it to my needs? which is the web hook url that DocuSign called in this case? I don't know php

Comment: Thanks Larry, but i think i'll need to take help from some python/php guy. On a different note do you think we can implement this DocuSign signing using native UI elements(not UIWebView) and rest apis? I went through DS documentation and cannot find any apis to implement this natively. The only way is obtaining the unique signing url and show it on a web view. Can we do this natively? Any REST apis available?

Comment: The only way for someone to sign is to use the DocuSign web view. You can brand it to match your app's colors, logo, etc. This is also true for web apps.